# Changing a test mail server environment to a production mail server with a different name

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I have set up a test environment as follows:  Domain / AD on Windows Server 2003.  Domain is example.com.  Test email is set up on Exchange 2010 on Windows 2008 R2.  I now want to go live and set up reality.com as my email.  Can I do this within the existing configuration or do I need to rename the domain and reconfigure Exchange from scratch?

Comment: Exchange Server has no idea that you "were only kidding". There's no real difference between setting it up to handle test/fake domains and setting it up to handle real domains. There's no technical reason that you shouldn't be able to use your existing Exchange Server for your real domains.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly.  I do not know how to create an additional domain on my DC / AD.  I did add reality.com as an Organizational Unit in AD, but it still utilizes the original domain name.  In DNS, I created a Forward Lookup Zone for reality.com.  Still does not allow me use reality.com for Exchange.  The Exchange utilizes the following: example.com/reality.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're a bit out of your depth. You don't (and can't) create an additional domain in AD and you don't need to create a new OU. You simply need to add the domain as an Accepted Domain in Exchange and modify your E-Mail Address Policy accordingly. Both of these can be found in the Exchange Management Console under `Organization Configuration|Hub Transport`.

Comment: Thank you.  I had added my domain as an Accepted Domain but did not modify the E-Mail Address Policy.  That seemed to do the trick.  Now, I need to figure out how to create MX records correctly!